# Java Generic List Template

Tags: java, list, templates, generics

I created a ListPrinter (main class) and a ListHolder class.

I was taught how to create a generic ArrayHolder but now I am trying to modify it (my homework) to a LIST Holder.

my teacher's Array printer code is:

```
 public class ArrayHolder <P>
 {
    P arr[];
    public void print(P arr2[],int count)
    {
        arr = arr2;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("\n"+arr[i]+"\n");
       }// end for
    }// end print method
}// end class.
```

I used this as a template for my ListHolder but I keep getting an error in the **sout** line:

```
public class ListHolder <x>
{ 
    x list ;     
    public  void print (x list2, int count) 
    {      
        list= list2;
        for (int i = 0; i < count;  i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(list2(i)+"\n");
        }
    } // end print
} //end class
```

what am I doing wrong???

==========
KayKay

It is still giving me errors :(
I copied and pasted your answer.
The first error is on the line:
List list;
the first LIST is underlined and the error is: Cannot find symbol

Second error is in the line under that:
public void print (List list2, int count)
LIST is underlined and the error is the same = cannot find symbol

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It seems correct (I suppose you don't add `list2(i)` but `list.get(i)`), do you check the value of count when calling the method ?

Comment: `list` is not necessarily a `Collection` type.

Comment: @Rohit Of course, but in all case (s)he needs a getter for the value... My compiler doesn't like list(i) ^^

Comment: My code compiles (I copy-pasted it too), you are probably missing the import to java.util.List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a `List` you need to use the `get(index)` method to retrieve an element by its index.

Also `x` is the type of what the list contains, not the type of the list itself. So the declaration should be `List<x> list`.

Here's your code with these modifications :

```
public class ListHolder <x>
{ 
    List<x> list ;     
    public  void print (List<x> list2, int count) 
    {      
        list= list2;
        for (int i = 0; i < count;  i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(list2.get(i)+"\n");
        }
    } // end print
} //end class
```

Comment: ListHolder<Dog> dogs = new ListHolder<Dog>();
        dogs.print(list, 5);
        
        ListHolder<Groceries> items = new ListHolder<Groceries>();
        items.print(list, 5);
        
        ListHolder<Staff> people = new ListHolder<Staff>();
        people.print(list, 5);
        

    } // end main

} //end class

Comment: You should put it in the question rather than in the comments. Your code shows as I thought that x is the type of what is in the list (Dog), so you need to replace "x" by "List<x>" in your ListHolder class.

Comment: How do I put in the question rather than the comments?

Comment: By clicking the "edit" link below your question. Keep me posted on if the code of my answer worked for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you could declare the class as `ListHolder<X extends List<?>>` to tell the compiler that the type X must be a list of something.